# PATCH in web API for Many to Many relationships using EF

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to remove a tag from a list of tags using a PATCH request. But while saving changes to the db context I get the following error:[image: dbcontext error].
This the the PATCH code.

```cs
[HttpPatch("{id:int}/{field}", Name = "UpdateNote")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public IActionResult UpdateNote(int id, string field, JsonPatchDocument<CreateNoteDTO> patchNoteDTO)
{
    if (id == 0 || patchNoteDTO == null)
        return BadRequest();
    var note = _db.Notes.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(u => u.ID == id);
    if (note == null)
        return NotFound();



    CreateNoteDTO createNoteDTO = _mapper.Map<CreateNoteDTO>(note);
    if (field.Equals("tags"))
    {
        var tags = _db.Tags.Where(u => u.Notes.Any(x => x.ID == note.ID)).AsNoTracking().ToList();
        List<TagDTO> tagDTOs = new List<TagDTO>();
        if (tags.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var tag in tags)
            {
                TagDTO tagDTO = _mapper.Map<TagDTO>(tag);
                tagDTOs.Add(tagDTO);
            }
        }
        createNoteDTO.Tags = tagDTOs;
    }
    patchNoteDTO.ApplyTo(createNoteDTO, ModelState);

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);



    Note updateNote = _mapper.Map<Note>(createNoteDTO);
    updateNote.ID = id;
    updateNote.ChangedDate = DateTime.Now;
    _db.Update(updateNote);
    if (!field.ToLower().Equals("category"))
        _db.Entry(updateNote).Property(u => u.FKCategory).IsModified = false;
    _db.Entry(updateNote).Property(u => u.CreatedDate).IsModified = false;
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return NoContent();
}
```

My ApplicationDBContext looks like this:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Write Fluent API configurations here

        modelBuilder.Entity<Note>()
                    .HasOne(e => e.Category)
                    .WithMany(e => e.Notes)
                    .HasForeignKey(e => e.FKCategory)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Note>()
                .HasMany(n => n.Tags)
                .WithMany(t => t.Notes)
                .UsingEntity(j => j
                .ToTable("NoteTag")
                .HasData
                (
                    new { NotesID = 1, TagsTagID = 1 },
                    new { NotesID = 2, TagsTagID = 2 }
                ));


        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasData
            (
            new Category
            {
                CategoryID = 1,
                CategoryName = "testCategory1",
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
            },
            new Category
            {
                CategoryID = 2,
                CategoryName = "testCategory2",
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
            }
            );
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>().HasData
            (
            new Tag
            {
                TagID = 1,
                TagName = "testTag1",
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
            },
            new Tag
            {
                TagID = 2,
                TagName = "testTag2",
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
            }
            );
        modelBuilder.Entity<Note>().HasData
            (
            new Note
            {
                ID = 1,
                Title = "testTitle1",
                Description = "testDescription1",
                FKCategory = 1,
                Deleted = false,
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                ChangedDate = DateTime.Now,
            },
            new Note
            {
                ID = 2,
                Title = "testTitle2",
                Description = "testDescription2",
                FKCategory = 2,
                Deleted = false,
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                ChangedDate = DateTime.Now,
            }
            );
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Initially I tried without the following if condition:

```cs
CreateNoteDTO createNoteDTO = _mapper.Map<CreateNoteDTO>(note);
if (field.Equals("tags"))
{
    var tags = _db.Tags.Where(u => u.Notes.Any(x => x.ID == note.ID)).AsNoTracking().ToList();
    List<TagDTO> tagDTOs = new List<TagDTO>();
    if (tags.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var tag in tags)
        {
            TagDTO tagDTO = _mapper.Map<TagDTO>(tag);
            tagDTOs.Add(tagDTO);
        }
    }
    createNoteDTO.Tags = tagDTOs;
}
```

But I got a different error:
[image: Error without the if condition]

I wanted to remove a tag form the following object using a PATCH request:
[Note Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28bbM.png)

Comment: I'm afraid it's by design, the error `cannot insert duplicated key ...` already explain the error clearly. And the second error message, where's the array? Hmm per my understanding, it's better to use list instead of array, because array need to define the size in advance.